# SSIS Help; move file based on condition

Tags: ssis

can you help me with a solution. I am not able to figure out and I have a tight deadline.

I need to read a file and based on if a column value contain any value greater than one.. i need to continue further processing or error out. Implying, if any (row)value in that column is greater than one, I need to move the file to error folder and if all values are 'one' need to move it to 'processed' folder. I have got the parts that reads the file..and moves the file complete. How can i check the column-value and error-out the file based on that?

Answer (score 1):

Could you check the Max value (using Aggregate transformation) in the data flow?  If it is greater than 1, then send the file to the error folder, otherwise send it to the processed folder.